# Basic syntax for an animation loop?

Tags: animation, loops, pseudocode, language-agnostic

I know that jQuery, for example, can do animation of sorts. I also know that at the very core of the animation, there must me some sort of loop doing the animation.  What is an example of such a loop?

A complete answer should ideally answer the following questions:

- What is a  basic syntax for an effective animation recursion that can animate a single property of a particular object at a time? The function should be able to vary its target object and property of the object.
- What arguments/parameters should it take?
- What is a good range of reiterating the loop? In milliseconds? (Should this be a parameter/argument to the function?)

REMEMBER:

- The answer is NOT necessarily language specific, but if you are writing in a specific language, please specify which one.
- Error handling is a plus. {Nothing is more irritating (for our purposes) than an  animation that does something strange, like stopping halfway through.}

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is open source, I suggest you look at the already available code rather than ask others to do your work for you.

Comment: @meagar - I have trouble reading jQuery code, I'm not sure why. I'll give it another go, though - for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically (for jQuery at least) this is not done in a loop, but rather in a series of callbacks.

pseudojavascript:

```
function startAnimation(element, endPosition, duration) {
    var startPosition = element.position;
    var startTime = getCurrentTime();
    function animate() {
        var timeElapsed = getCurrentTime() - startTime;
        if (timeElapsed > duration) {
            element.position = endPosition;
            stopTimer();
        } else {
            // interpolate based on time
            element.position = startPosition +
                (endPosition - startPosition) * timeElapsed / duration;
        }
    }
    startRepeatingTimerWithCallbackAndInterval(animate, 1.0 / 30.0);
}
```

It's also possible to use objects to store starting data instead of closures.

This doesn't completely answer all the points in the question, but it's a starting point.

Comment: *using namespace my.knowledge; "closures" == undefined.* **English:** I'm not sure what "closures" means.

Comment: a closure refers to the function `animate` being able to access the local variables inside `startAnimation` even after `startAnimation` has returned. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml has some examples of them in javascript